# Невозможно создать экземпляр абстрактного класса!

Tags: c++

Жалуется на PO, OS, и Driver: Невозможно создать экземпляр абстрактного класса

```
  //главный файл  
          #include <iostream>
            #include <Windows.h>
            #include <locale>
            #include "class.h"
            using namespace std;
            int main()
            {
                setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
                SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
                SetConsoleCP(1251);
                cout << "-----------------------------------Конструктор с параметрами-----------------------------------\n";
                PO* po1 = new PO("Фёрст", 2222, 981);
                po1->output();
                OS* os1 = new OS(1, 2, "Влад", "Шоколад");
                os1->output();
                Driver* driver1 = new Driver("Первая", 2, "Третья");
                driver1->output();
                cout << "-----------------------------------Конструктор по умолчанию-----------------------------------\n";
                PO* po = new PO();
                po->output();
                OS* os = new OS();
                os->output();
                Driver* driv = new Driver();
                driv->output();
                cout << "-----------------------------------Ввод через сеттеры-----------------------------------\n";
                po->input();
                os->input();
                po->output();
                os->output();
                cout << "Это были данные об ОС, теперь идём к драйверам: \n";
                po->input();
                driv->input();
                po->output();
                driv->output();
                delete po;
                delete po1;
                delete os;
                delete os1;
                delete driv;
                delete driver1;
                return 0;
            }
        //файл класса
        #pragma once
        using namespace std;
        class PO {
        protected:
            string developer;
            int year;
            int version;
        public:
            virtual void pozdnee() = 0;
            PO();
            PO(string first, int two, int version);
            virtual void setDeveloper(string developer) {
                this->developer = developer;
            };
            virtual void setYear(int year) {
                this->year = year;
            };
            virtual void setVersion(int version) {
                this->version = version;
            };
            string getDeveloper();
            virtual void input();
            virtual void output();
        };
        
        class OS : public PO {
        private:
            int razryad;
            int tasks;
            string type;
            string platform;
        public:
            OS();
            OS(int first, int second, string three, string fourth);
            virtual void setRazryad(int razryad) {
                this->razryad = razryad;
            };
            virtual void setTasks(int tasks) {
                this->tasks = tasks;
            };
            virtual void setType(string type) {
                this->type = type;
            };
            virtual void setPlatform(string platform) {
                this->platform = platform;
            };
            virtual void input();
            virtual void output();
        };
        
        class Driver : public PO {
        private:
            string devicetype;
            long long int indentificator;
            string OS;
        public:
            Driver();
            Driver(string first, long long second, string threeth);
            virtual void setDevicetype(string devicetype) {
                this->devicetype = devicetype;
            }
            virtual void setIndentificator(long long int indentificator) {
                this->indentificator = indentificator;
            }
            virtual void setOS(string OS) {
                this->OS = OS;
            }
            virtual void input();
            virtual void output();
        };
    
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <locale>
    #include <string>
    #include "class.h"
    using namespace std;
    
    PO::PO() {
        //cout << "------------------------------------------КОНСТРУКТОР ПО УМОЛЧАНИЮ------------------------------------------\n";
        this->developer = "Digger Online";
        this->year = 2001;
        this->version = 91;
    }
    
    PO::PO(string first, int two, int threeth) {
        this->developer = first;
        this->year = two;
        this->version = threeth;
    }
    
    void PO::input() {
        string developer;
        int year;
        int version;
        cout << "Разработчик: ";
        getline(cin, developer);
        //getline(cin, developer);
        this->setDeveloper(developer);
        cout << "Год выпуска: ";
        cin >> year;
        while (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            //cout << "ГОД: ";
            cin >> year;
        }
        cin.ignore();
        this->setYear(year);
        cout << "Версия: ";
        cin >> version;
        while (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            //cout << "Версия: ";
            cin >> version;
        }
        this->setVersion(version);
        cin.ignore();
    }
    
    string PO::getDeveloper() {
        return developer;
    }
    
    OS::OS() {
        //cout << "------------------------------------------КОНСТРУКТОР ПО УМОЛЧАНИЮ(OS)------------------------------------------\n";
        this->setRazryad(64);
        this->setTasks(1);
        this->setType("ТИП");
        this->setPlatform("ПЛАТФОРМА");
    }
    
    OS::OS(int first, int second, string three, string fourth) {
        //cout << "------------------------------------------КОНСТРУКТОР ПО УМОЛЧАНИЮ(OS)------------------------------------------\n";
        this->setRazryad(first);
        this->setTasks(second);
        this->setType(three);
        this->setPlatform(fourth);
    }
    
    Driver::Driver() {
        this->setDevicetype("Devycetype");
        this->setIndentificator(12125125125);
        this->setOS("Windows");
    }
    
    Driver::Driver(string first, long long second, string threeth) {
        this->setDevicetype(first);
        this->setIndentificator(second);
        this->setOS(threeth);
    }
    
    void OS::input() {
        //cout << "------------------------------------------ВВОД ДАННЫХ ОБ ОС------------------------------------------\n";
        //cout << getDeveloper() << "\n";
        int razryad;
        int tasks;
        string type;
        string platform;
        cout << "Разряд: ";
        cin >> razryad;
        while (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Разрядность: ";
            cin >> razryad;
        }
        while (razryad != 32 && razryad != 64) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Разряд: ";
            cin >> razryad;
        }
        cin.ignore();
        this->setRazryad(razryad);
        cout << "Многозадачный?(1 - да; 0 - нет): ";
        cin >> tasks;
        cin.ignore();
        while (tasks < 1 || tasks > 2 || cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Многозадачный?(1 - да; 0 - нет): ";
            cin >> tasks;
            cin.ignore();
        }
        this->setTasks(tasks);
        cout << "Тип: ";
        getline(cin, type);
        this->setType(type);
        cout << "Платформа: ";
        getline(cin, platform);
        this->setPlatform(platform);
    }
    //Второй исполняемый файл
    void Driver::input() {
        //cout << "------------------------------------------ВВОД ДАННЫХ ОБ ОС------------------------------------------\n";
        //cout << getDeveloper() << "\n";
        string type;
        string OS;
        long long int indentificator;
        cout << "Тип устройства: ";
        getline(cin, type);
        //cin.ignore();
        this->setDevicetype(type);
        cout << "Индентификатор: ";
        cin >> indentificator;
        cin.ignore();
        this->setIndentificator(indentificator);
        cout << "ОС: ";
        getline(cin, OS);
        //cin.ignore();
        this->setOS(OS);
    }
    
    
    void PO::output() {
        cout << this->developer << "\n";
        cout << this->year << "\n";
        cout << this->version << "\n";
    }
    
    void OS::output() {
        cout << this->razryad << "\n";
        if (this->tasks == 1) {
            cout << "Многозадачный" << endl;
        }
        else cout << "Не многозадачный" << endl;
        cout << this->type << "\n";
        cout << this->platform << "\n";
    }
    void Driver::output() {
        //cout << developer << " <--------- Пример наследования(да-да, это писал я, Влад Ламеко)\n";
        cout << this->devicetype << "\n";
        cout << this->indentificator << "\n";
        cout << this->OS << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: 1) Вы не могли потратить немного больше времени и отформатировать выложенный код?? 2) А что вам не понятно? Вы не можете создать экземпляр абстрактного класса!

Comment: Т.е по сути, чтобы создать чисто виртуальный метод, мне нужно создать отдельный класс для него?

Comment: Вы не можете инстанциировать абстрактный класс. Но вы можете от него унаследоваться. И создать экземпляр класса-наследника.

Comment: У вас  `pozdnee` - это чистая виртуальная функция, которая должна быть переопределена в классе наследнике. То есть нужно в классах `OS` и `Driver` переопределить функцию `pozdnee`. Но `PO` у вас так же останется абстрактным классом, экземпляр которого нельзя будет создать

Comment: Судя по приведенному вами коду, вам эта `pozdnee()` просто не нужна вообще. Так **зачем** вы ее ввели как чисто абстрактную виртуальную функцию? Может, убрать ее вообще?